# how to detect scroll or zoom on mapkit with touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, touch, mapkit, uitouch

I create one mapkit app that in this show my location and update this location every time and set this location in center of view. I update my location and set in center with Boolean variable.
I want detect scroll or zoom touch finger on my map and when I do it my boolean variable changed and don't set my location on center but I don't know about handling touch event on mapkit.

please guide me about that and tell me how to change my variable when touching and scroll map.
thanks.
this is my code:

```
@implementation ViewController
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    double latitudes;
    double longitudes;
    BOOL updateLocation;
}
@synthesize mapView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    updateLocation = YES;
    mapView = [[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
    mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
    mapView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I'm Here"];
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
    mapView.delegate = self;

    [self GetMyLocation];


}
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
            NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
            UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [errorAlert show];
        }
        - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
            CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

            if (currentLocation != nil) {
                longitudes = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
                latitudes = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
                //NSLog(@"%f,%f",longitudes,latitudes);
                //[self centerLocation];
            }
        }



#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate
            - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
                if (updateLocation) {
                    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
                    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:NO];
                }
                else{NSLog(@"Don't Update");}
            }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use:

```
mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:
```

which tells the delegate that the region displayed by the map view is about to change.

> This method is called whenever the currently displayed map region
>   changes. During scrolling, this method may be called many times to
>   report updates to the map position. Therefore, your implementation of
>   this method should be as lightweight as possible to avoid affecting
>   scrolling performance.

Based on [MKMapViewDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/MKMapViewDelegate/mapView%3aregionWillChangeAnimated%3a)

Comment: thanks dude. what's different between 
– mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:
– mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `MKMapView` delegate methods bellow

```
– mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:
– mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift** just you should use from following code

```
extension UIViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
     func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {}
}
```